# Can N and B be graphed when undefined?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, frenet-frame

I was asked to graph T, N, and B on a 3 dimensional graph. In this case, N(0) and B(0) are both undefined. Is there a way to graph them? I will include a picture of my work on the problem so you can see what I am talking about. 
[image]

Comment: ??? What you post appears to have calculated N(0) as <0, 0, 1> and B(0) as $\left<\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}}, 0\right>$.

What do you mean by saying they "don't exist"?

Comment: @user247327 see edits